# Input to determine how many datasets to pull from

Tags: sql

Hopefully this will make sense:

Basically I want the user to input a variable at the start to determine how many datasets they want to compare:

```
DECLARE @NumberOfRuns INT
SET @NumberOfRuns = (1,2,3.. normally just 2)
```

After this I will have a query on multiple datasets:

```
SELECT*
FROM (Dataset 1)
UNION ALL
SELECT*
FROM (Dataset 2)
```

Is there a way that if the input for `@NumberOfRuns = 1` it only runs the first part, and if the input was 2 it would run both?

Comment: Can you tag which version of SQL you are using too? sql-server, mysql, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which rdbms? sql-server, mysql oracle? etc.  For the non-dynamic route one other method is to use temp table

```
CREATE TABLE #TempTable (
    --Columns And DataTypes of Select Statements
)

INSERT INTO #TempTable (columns)
SELECT *
FROM
    Dataset 1

IF @NumberOfRuns >= 2
INSERT INTO #TempTable (columns)
SELECT *
FROM
    Dataset 2

IF @NumberOfRuns >= 3
INSERT INTO #TempTable (columns)
SELECT *
FROM
    Dataset 3

SELECT *
FROM
    #TempTable
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do an IF ... ELSE ... and hard code it into

```
IF @NumberOfRuns = 1
    SELECT * FROM Dataset1 

IF @NumberOfRuns = 2
    SELECT * FROM Dataset1 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM Dataset2

IF @NumberOfRuns = 3
    SELECT * FROM Dataset1 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM Dataset2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM Dataset3
```

etc...

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server you could just write your union **ONCE** and pull it into a #Temp and then filter on a column you set.

```
select
1 as ColumnID
....
INTO #Temp
....
UNION ALL
SELECT
2 as ColumnID
....
UNION ALL
SELECT
3 as ColumnID
....

SELECT * FROM #Temp WHERE ColumnID <= @NumberOfRuns
```